# Django: objects and model_set

Tags: python, django

I am learning django 1.10 official tutorial part 2

```
class  Question(models.Model):
  # ......

class Choice(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  #.......
```

Recent i saw the following command:-

```
q = Question.objects.get(id=1)
q.choice_set.all()
```

My questions:-

How Question instance contain `choice_set`, i know it for  accessing related objects.

Why is this not valid

```
c = Choice.objects.get(id=1)
c.question_set.all()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Question model does not have an **explicit** reference to the Choice model; however, Django automatically adds a reverse-reference, which is by default called choice_set. You can override this by *related_name* keyword on the model such as:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='choices')
```

Now you can reference all of the choices for a question like this:

```
q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
q.choices.all()
```

To answer your second question, the reason you cannot use reference **question_set.all()** from a **choice** object is because for each choice, there is only one question plus there is an **explicit** reference to the question object. In other words the Choice model already has a field called **Question**, which points to the Question model.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, i also referred to  `RelatedManager` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference. Can you link where i can get such information for future references.

Comment: This information and a lot more is available in the official Django documentation at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/